# Why are the number of upvotes and downvotes not shown separately?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, vote-count

In all Stack Exchange sites we have an option for upvoting and downvoting. Now, I see that for a question one upvote is worth +5 reputation while a downvote is worth -2.

Now, there is a difference in value but, when a question with 1 upvote is downvoted it becomes 0. So,this value for upvote and downvote is same but the reputation value is not same.

Is it ok? Why don't we have a separate tabs beside the question that shows *this number of upvotes* and *this number of downvotes*?

Comment: You can _earn_ this privilege upon reaching 1000 reputation.  But you can read the duplicated question linked for a discussion about that.